# Select rows by most recent year

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, subset

I have a data frame of vegetation metrics collected at x units and y sampling stations (multiple stations within each unit) over multiple years. I want to select all the vegetation data for each unit for the most recent year that data has been collected. Here is an example of my data frame:

```
veg <- c("tree","grass","tree","grass","tree","grass","tree","grass")
cover <- c(0.97,0.21,0.35,0.67,0.45,0.72,0.27,0.67)
unit <- c("U1","U1","U1","U1","U2","U2","U2","U2")
station <- c("A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3","A4","A4")
year <- c(2015,2015,2014,2014,2013,2013,2014,2014)
df <- data.frame(veg,cover,unit,station,year)
```

The data frame looks like this:

```
    veg cover unit station year
1  tree  0.97   U1      A1 2015
2 grass  0.21   U1      A1 2015
3  tree  0.35   U1      A2 2014
4 grass  0.67   U1      A2 2014
5  tree  0.45   U2      A3 2013
6 grass  0.72   U2      A3 2013
7  tree  0.27   U2      A4 2014
8 grass  0.67   U2      A4 2014
```

I want it to look like this:

```
    veg cover unit station year
1  tree  0.97   U1      A1 2015
2 grass  0.21   U1      A1 2015
3  tree  0.27   U2      A4 2014
4 grass  0.67   U2      A4 2014
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you want the recent years? Do you want to define 'recent year'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is how to do it without any package.

```
df.by     = by(df, df$unit, FUN = function(t) t[t$year == max(t$year),])
df.recent = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), df.by)
df.recent
```

The output is

```
>     df.recent
    veg cover unit station year
1 grass  0.21   U1      A1 2015
2 grass  0.67   U2      A4 2014
3  tree  0.27   U2      A4 2014
4  tree  0.97   U1      A1 2015
```

For the first line, we use the function `by` to subset the data frame by the factor `df$unit`. For each subset (for each unit) , we extract the row of the recent year by the anonymous function `function(t) t[t$year == max(t$year),])`.

df.by is a list of data frames which contains only the rows of most recent year for each unit.

For the second line, we use the the `merge` function to merge all the data frame in `df.by`. The use of this code is explain in [Simultaneously merge multiple data.frames in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list) .

Answer (score 0):

This gets your answer, you want the most recent by veg/unit right?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(veg, unit) %>% 
    arrange(desc(year)) %>% 
    slice(1)
```